# How to get TableHeaderRow from TableView nowadays in JavaFX 10?

Tags: javafx, tableview, java-platform-module-system, java-10, tableheader

i want to customize the tableheader in a tableview. this example works fine in javaFx8.

```
  TableViewSkin<?> skin = ( TableViewSkin<?> )getSkin();
  TableHeaderRow tableHeader = skin.getTableHeaderRow();
  NestedTableColumnHeader rootHeader = tableHeader.getRootHeader();

  tableHeader.setReordering( false );
```

Now i changed the jre to Java 10 with all the jigsaw changes so that all the internal api isn't accessable anymore.
So the methods getTableHeaderRow() / getRootHeader() / setReordering() are private now, so the only way to acces them is via reflection, which i don't want to use, because i am not a friend of them.

So is there a way to cusomize the tableheader in JavaFx10 ?

In my opinion it was easy from Oracle to make these changes but they don't give us developers a solution to solve such problems with a new api, they just make everything private or protected.

We are doing a lot of customize controls and using a lot of "internal" api and now we have huge effort to to run the fine working code from Java 8 to Java 10.

Comment: Surely if you use internal/private API you are basically accepting that your application will not be compatible with future releases of the library. Isn't the whole point of a private API that the authors have the freedom to change it between releases? Your options are to stick with Java 8, to use the reflective hack you mention, or to rewrite the table skin pretty much from scratch.

Comment: The `Skin`s are implementation specific and can't be trusted. What would be nice is for access to the tableheaders as part of the `TableView` interface, but alas... Please list everything you use from the `Skin` and we might be able to provide alternatives. Eg. for setting reorderable you can just set it for each `TableColumn` rather than going through the `Skin`.

Comment: @xtratic In Java 9, though, the Skins were made part of the public API; so the functionality of the Skins that are now exposed through that API can at least be trusted. Admittedly, that is currently a *very* thin API, and certainly not enough to do what the OP is asking to do here. At least it is slowly heading in the right direction though.

Comment: thank you for your answers, the Setting for reordering was just an example i solved in this way:      getColumns().forEach( e ->
      {
        e.setReorderable( false );
      } );

Comment: @James_D I was thinking along the lines that Skins should be avoided since the implementation being `TableViewSkin` isn't guaranteed: for example a user could set a default style-sheet that specifies the Skin implementation to be `MyTableViewSkinWithWeirdHeaders`. Though, in that unlikely case, it's really on them and you can decide if you want to deal with such users or not...

Answer (score 0):

`skin.getTableHeaderRow()` is `protected access`, but I saw this somewhere:

```
TableHeaderRow headerRow = (TableHeaderRow) tableView.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
```